# How to highlight dates with jQuery's datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using *Jquery UI datepicker* to allow a user to fill a date input by selecting a date out of a displayed a calendar.

So far, everything works as expected : http://jsfiddle.net/Aut9b/374/

Then, I wanted to highlight certain dates, to help the user choose, so I looked into the `beforeShowDay` option which makes that possible.

> beforeShowDayType: Function( Date date )
>
> ```
> Default: null
>
> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
>
>   [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable 
>   [1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation 
>   [2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
>
> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.
> ```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Aut9b/375/

The next step is not only to highlight certain dates but to do it dynamically, based on what the user had previously selected in other inputs (in the same form), so I have used `ajax` in order to retrieve the dates to highlight

This is my (incomplete) code so far.

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
}); 

function fillDates() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
                var highlight = dates[date];
                if( highlight ) {
                    return [true, 'highlight', highlight];
                } else {
                    return [true, '', ''];
                }
            }
        });
}   

function getDates() {
    $.ajax({    
        type : "POST", 
        dataType: "text",
        url : "ajaxFindDates",
        data : {departure:$('#departure option:selected').val(),
            arrival:$('#arrival option:selected').val()},

        success : function(data) {              
            var dateStr = JSON.parse(data);
            var dates=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < dateStr.length; i++) {
                date=new Date(dateStr[i]);
                dates.push(date);
            }
            fillDates(dates);
        }
            ,
            error : function(data) {
                alert("Problem!" );
            }
        }); 
}
```

The function `getDates()` is called when the value of the `<select>` changes.

I have tried to debug using the browser developer tool and it seems that the function defined in the `beforeShowDay` is never executed.

Any help will be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Is your ajax executed in success state?

Comment: Also, it is redundant to use ` dataType: "text",` and then `var dateStr = JSON.parse(data);`. You could simpy use `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: yes, it is. this is the returned data (for example) : "["2015-09-12","2015-09-11"]"

Comment: Can you insert the "console.log( dates[0], date )" code in beforeShowDay function and write the result.

Comment: I just tried and no result, it seems like the beforeShowDay function is not executed [Link](http://i.imgur.com/fopr0Uk.png)

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when `ajax` gets in success state, you need to destroy datepicker instance and then create it again in order to trigger `beforeShowDay`.

You can do it by calling:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
```

Then, you are checking if date exists in your `dates` array with sush a statement:

```
var highlight = dates[date];
```

In other words, you check the key, but when creating `dates` array you just `push()` dates to array making simple numeric indexes:

```
dates.push(date);
```

If keep it without changes, I think that you will never find them. You should change the way you find elements in array, or the way you add them into the array.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aut9b/379/). I have mocked ajax request there. Keep in mind that I have also changed the format of the dates recived from the server to `mm/dd/yyyy`(09/09/2015). With the format that you have provided in your comments, the indexes in final array where not identic.

Comment: Thanx a lot, i had already figured out the first part but not the date format thing, that's what was causing the trouble. Now it finally works!

Answer (score 2):

Your `fillDates` function doesn't have a `dates` argument.

```
function fillDates(dates) {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
            var highlight = dates[date];
            if( highlight ) {
                return [true, 'highlight', highlight];
            } else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please check your dates array values. It has to be JavaScript date object. I think you don't store it like JavaScript date object.

Can you try this? Please

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
}); 

function fillDates() {

        // Please select your specific DOM.
        var datepickerSelect = $('.datepicker').eq(0);

        datepickerSelect.datepicker("destroy").datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
            beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
                var highlight = dates[date];
                if( highlight ) {
                    return [true, 'highlight', highlight];
                } else {
                    return [true, '', ''];
                }
            }
        });
}   

function getDates() {
    $.ajax({    
        type : "POST", 
        dataType: "text",
        url : "ajaxFindDates",
        data : {departure:$('#departure option:selected').val(),
            arrival:$('#arrival option:selected').val()},

        success : function(data) {              
            var dateStr = JSON.parse(data);
            var dates=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < dateStr.length; i++) {
                date=new Date(dateStr[i]);
                dates.push(date);
            }
            fillDates(dates);
        }
            ,
            error : function(data) {
                alert("Problem!" );
            }
        }); 
}
```

Comment: I think `dates` can be accessed because this variable is declared in a higher scope.

Comment: nope. variable declared in getDates function. you can see it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error but it doesn't solve the main issue

Comment: I think its indeed stored as Js date object : [here is prtscreen](http://i.imgur.com/fopr0Uk.png), isn't it ?

Comment: @RamziGhaddab I removed my comment when i see your date object. I updated my answer with all of your JavaScript code.

Comment: @ebilgin thanks, i tried the updated code you posted, the filldates function is missing the "dates" argument, once that added, it works, the beforeShowDate is finally executed! however my dates are not highlighted, so i added in the function "console.log(highlight)" and its says the var highlight is undefined

Comment: @RamziGhaddab what is the exact place of your console.log( highlight ) code ?

Comment: @ebilgin just after the variable is defined, i also tried console.log(dates[date]); and end up with same result. If you have a better idea to find out why the selected dates are not highlighted, please let me know. It's not a css issue because i removed all the css except the one needed.

Comment: Problem solved ! Thanks again for your help, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the changes in your jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/Aut9b/377/

```js
window.your_dates = [new Date("15-Sep-2015").toString()]
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            // check if date is in your array of dates
            if($.inArray(date.toString(), your_dates)) {
                console.log(your_dates);
                // if it is return the following.
                return [true, 'css-class-to-highlight', 'tooltip text'];
            } else {
                // default
                return [true, '', ''];
            }                                        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
#highlight, .highlight {
    /*background-color: #000000;*/
}
.css-class-to-highlight > a.ui-state-default {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_25_ffef8f_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% top #FFEF8F !important;
    border: 1px solid #F9DD34;
    color: #363636;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="input" class="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my issue, although it made me notice that the beforeShowDay function is only executed when the datepicker function is called inside the $(function{})