# How to highlight the dates using ajax codeiginter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have looked through some code in stack overflow the link is [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628940/how-to-highlight-dates-with-jquerys-datepicker)

I have tired this code but i didn't got result correctly.

script code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           $(function() {
               $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
               });
               getDates();
            }); 

            function fillDates(dates) {            
                $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy').datepicker({

                    beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
                        var highlight = dates[date];
                        if( highlight ) {
                            return [true, 'highlight', highlight];
                        } else {
                            return [true, '', ''];
                        }
                    }
                });
            }   

            function getDates() {
                console.log('ada');
                $.ajax({    
                    type : "POST",                 
                     url: '/echo/json/',
                    data: {
                        json: JSON.stringify(["09/09/2020","12/09/2020"]),
                        delay: 1
                    },
                    success : function(data) {                                 
                        data = JSON.stringify(data);
                        var dateStr = JSON.parse(data);
                        var dates={};
                        for (var i = 0 ; i < dateStr.length; i++) {
                            date= new Date(dateStr[i]);
                            dates[date] = date;
                        }                    
                        fillDates(dates);
                    },
                    error : function(data) {
                        alert("Problem!" );
                    }
               }); 
            }

        });
```

I got an alert as problem. i don't know how to find errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use the console.error() to log your errors.

This

```
error : function(data) {
                     alert("Problem!" );
                    }
```

can be changed to

```
error: function(err){

  console.error(err.statusText)
}
```

Also, enable the browser's developer tools and at the Network section, check the request that you sent and you'll know its status of the response, if an error did occurred at your backed, you'll be able to see why.

Comment: see this link http://jsfiddle.net/pkty4jq3/ here it work well

Comment: no i am not getting result correctly in local host only js fiddle it working

Comment: what error do you see in the console, also when you post the form, do you see any error(s) as you track the browser's developer's tool Network request/response status?